# Remove specific entry from Lua table

Tags: lua, lua-table

I am inserting into a table like this

`Admin = {}`

```
table.insert(Admins, {id = playerId, Count = 0})
```

And that works fine.

How do I remove that specific admin from that table now?

The following does not work, and Im sure its because ID is stored in an array that's inside of the table, but how would I access that then?

```
table.remove(Admins, playerId)
```

Basically, 
I want to remove from the table Admins, where the ID == playerId that I input.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two approaches to remove an entry from the table, both are acceptable ways:

> **1. myTable[index] = nil** 
> Removes an entry from given index, but adds a hole in the table by maintaining the indices

```
local Admins = {}
table.insert(Admins, {id = 10, Count = 0})
table.insert(Admins, {id = 20, Count = 1})
table.insert(Admins, {id = 30, Count = 2})
table.insert(Admins, {id = 40, Count = 3})


local function removebyKey(tab, val)
    for i, v in ipairs (tab) do 
        if (v.id == val) then
          tab[i] = nil
        end
    end
end
-- Before
-- [1] = {['Count'] = 0, ['id'] = 10},
-- [2] = {['Count'] = 1, ['id'] = 20},
-- [3] = {['Count'] = 2, ['id'] = 30},
-- [4] = {['Count'] = 3, ['id'] = 40}}
removebyKey(Admins, 20)
-- After
-- [1] = {['Count'] = 0, ['id'] = 10},
-- [3] = {['Count'] = 2, ['id'] = 30},
-- [4] = {['Count'] = 3, ['id'] = 40}
```

> **2. table.remove(myTable, index)**
>  
>   Removes the entry from given index and renumbering the indices

```
local function getIndex(tab, val)
    local index = nil
    for i, v in ipairs (tab) do 
        if (v.id == val) then
          index = i 
        end
    end
    return index
end
local idx = getIndex(Admins, 20) -- id = 20 found at idx = 2
if idx == nil then 
    print("Key does not exist")
else
    table.remove(Admins, idx) -- remove Table[2] and shift remaining entries
end
-- Before is same as above
-- After entry is removed. Table indices are changed
-- [1] = {['id'] = 10, ['Count'] = 0},
-- [2] = {['id'] = 30, ['Count'] = 2},
-- [3] = {['id'] = 40, ['Count'] = 3}
```

Comment: Table is built same way as you posted

Comment: For case 1, the After output would be only
-- [1] = {['Count'] = 0, ['id'] = 10},
because ipairs would stop at the first nil value.
Using pairs would give the output you show.